# Controls of FormArray not displayed correctly after removing a control

Tags: angular

I have a component with a list of inputs in a FormArray. When I  try to remove one of the controls the last of the controls disappears instead of the one selected, but if I save the form the list of inputs are displayed correctly (the one I removed is not displayed and the last one is displayed).

This is my code:

component1.component.html

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
    <div [formArrayName]="name">
        <div *ngFor="let row of formArr.controls; let i=index; trackBy: trackByIndex" [formGroupName]="i">
            <input type="text" formControlName="text" />
            <!-- Other inputs, selects... -->
            <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true" (click)="removeOcurrence(i)"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

component1.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'component1',
    templateUrl: './component1.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./component1.component.scss']
})

export class Component1 {
    ...
    private _form: FormGroup;
    private _formArr: FormArray;
    private _name: string;

    @Input() set form(form: FormGroup) {
        this._form = form;
    }

    get form(): FormGroup {
        return this._form;
    }

    @Input() set formArr(formArr: FormArray) {
        this._formArr = formArr;
    }

    get formArr(): FormArray {
        return this._formArr;
    }

    @Input() set name(name: string) {
        this._name = name;
    }

    get name(): string {
        return this._name;
    }

    removeOcurrence(index: number): void {
        this._formArr.removeAt(index);
    }

    trackByIndex(index: number): number {
        return index;
    }

    ...
}
```

Example:

[image]

If for example I click on the second "X" to try to remove the second element, only the third element disappears (([first, second] is displayed), but if after it I save the form and refresh the page I get the correct list ([first, third]).

So it seems like the ngFor is not refreshing after removing.

Comment: Could you try removing the `trackBy` declaration from `ngFor`?, it seems that you dont need it and is creating a mismatch with the real index that you need to remove.

Comment: I think the problem is in `trackByIndex` because you remove index `1` (second row) but then it checks for changes and index `1` still exists because you're iterating `formArr.controls` array.

Comment: Thanks, it's working removing the trackBy

Comment: @martin Any idea why the behavior is? I mean what happens underneath/in depth?